# How to use Rcpp sugar function(mean,var) with vector<double>?

Tags: r, rcpp, syntactic-sugar

```
vector<double> Stock::getReturns(unsigned n){
vector<double> returnSelect;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    returnSelect.push_back(returns[i]);
return returnSelect;
}

double Stock::getMeanReturn(unsigned n){
double m=0;
vector<double> vec=getReturns(n);
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    m+=vec[i];
}
m=m/n;
return m;
};
```

These code with `vector<double>` works perfectly, but when I replace `vector<double>` with `NumericVector`, I could build the code in Eclipse, but it crashed when I ran it. `NumericVector` seems to be the problem.

```
Rcpp::NumericVector Stock::getReturns(unsigned n){
Rcpp::NumericVector returnSelect;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    returnSelect.push_back(returns[i]);
return returnSelect;
}

double Stock::getMeanReturn(unsigned n){
double m;
Rcpp::NumericVector vec=getReturns(n);
m=mean(vec);
return m;
};
```

So the question is why Eclipse can't deal with `NumericVector`? and is there any other method to use the Rcpp sugar if it doesn't take `NumericVector`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. First off, `Rcpp sugar` works only on Rcpp types as all these sugar functions are explicitly programmed -- and they are programmed for R types in their Rcpp presentation.
2. Second, your initial example is wrong.  You cannot do `m+=vec[i];` without having `vec` defined/declared somewhere. What is its size? Is the space reserved?  I think you got lucky there.
3. Third, please just don't state 'it crashed' without a reproducible example.
4. Eclipse has nothing to do with it, but you may have set your environment up the wrong way.